# Reuse of Lightswitch visual query designer

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

We are building application with ability for users to extract data without typing SQL queries. LightSwitch query designer looks user friendly.

Is it possible to reuse (embed) LightSwitch visual query designer into .NET application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can not reuse that editor (which is part of visual studio) in the Silverlight or HTML app.

However, there's a filter control extension available that might fulfill the same needs.  See Michael's post for some screenshots & guidelines: http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/22/Using-The-LightSwitch-Filter-Extension.aspx

Keep rocking LS!